# How to replace values in a matrix according to a list index in R?

Tags: r, list, replace

I have a matrix "m" with two columns and 664 rows; Each m[x,y] has a value that ranges from 1 to 889.

e.g.

```
nrow   ncol

1       3
1       250
1       341
2       212
2       452
....
```

On the other hand, I have a list of 889 strings that contain factors extracted from a database;

e.g.

```
List
[1]   TORNADOS
[2]   EXTREME WEATHER
[3]   TORNADO
[4]   VOLCANO ERUPTION
....
```

I want to replace the numbers in the first matrix by the character values in the list according to their index.

e.g.

```
nrow   ncol      ---->     nrow     ncol
1      3                   TORNADOS TORNADO
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is called `mat` and the list of strings is called `x` you could do

```
mat[] <- x[c(mat)]
```

Consider a reproducible example,

```
x <- c("TORNADOS", "EXTREME WEATHER", "TORNADO", "VOLCANO ERUPTION")
mat <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2), nrow = 5)
mat
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    1    4
#[3,]    1    4
#[4,]    2    1
#[5,]    2    2

mat[] <- x[c(mat)]
mat
#           [,1]              [,2]              
#[1,] "TORNADOS"        "TORNADO"         
#[2,] "TORNADOS"        "VOLCANO ERUPTION"
#[3,] "TORNADOS"        "VOLCANO ERUPTION"
#[4,] "EXTREME WEATHER" "TORNADOS"        
#[5,] "EXTREME WEATHER" "EXTREME WEATHER"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
cbind(nrow = m[List[,1], ncol = m[List[,2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code written by @akrun might be subject to error. I don't have a reputation to comment so I post my revision here. Here is my version of the solution:

```
cbind(nrow = List[m[,1]], ncol = List[m[,2]])
```